# finding the radius of convergence of a sequence

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

could you please look and verify if what i did is correct? i am requested to find the radius of convergence for those two sequences(sums):

1)$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{n!}{\left(2n\right)!}x^n$

2)$\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(1-x\right)^{5n}}{nln\left(n\right)\cdot 5^n}$

what i did:

1)$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{n!}{\left(2n\right)!}x^n$, i did the ratio test:$ \lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\left|\frac{\frac{\left(n+1\right)!x^{\left(n+1\right)}}{\left(2\left(n+1\right)\right)!}}{\frac{n!x^n}{\left(2n\right)!}}\right|\right) $, to obtain that $\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\left|\frac{x}{2\left(2n+1\right)}\right|\right)$, took $|\frac{x}{2}|$ out, $\left|\frac{x}{2}\right|\cdot \lim \:_{n\to \infty \:}\left(\left|\frac{1}{2n+1}\right|\right)$, so basically $\left|\frac{x}{2}\right|\cdot \lim \:_{n\to \infty \:}\left(\left|\frac{1}{2n+1}\right|\right)%$, which means that $x=0$. since x=0, does it mean that it converges for all x? ($(-\infty,\infty)$)

2)rearrenged, $(\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }\left(1-x\right)^{5n})(\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{nln\left(n\right)\cdot 5^n})$, now it seems that the root test is easier with the root test:$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{nln\left(n\right)\cdot \:5^n}}\right)$ = $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{nln\left(n\right)\cdot \:5^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ =$\frac{1}{1*1*1*5}$=$\frac{1}{5}$, and the second sequence is: $\sum _{n=2}^{\infty \:}\left(1-x\right)^{5n}$, using the root test again: $\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\left|\left(\left(1-x\right)^{5n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right|\right)$ = $\left|\left(1-x\right)^5\right|\cdot \lim \:_{n\to \infty \:}\left(\left|1\right|\right)$ . now checking $\left|\left(1-x\right)^5\right|<1$, which gives the range (0,2). so what is the range of convergence in this case?

what i did is correct? if i did any mistake, please correct me so i can learn and improve.
thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You mean *series*, not sequence. A sequence is a list of numbers, e.g. $\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5},\ldots$. This **sequence** tends to $0$. A **series** is what you get when you add the terms of a sequence, e.g. $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\cdots$. This series diverges.

Comment: thank you very much for explaining. english is unfortunately not my mother language, but i do my best to learn the correct terminology. please note that i fixed the second question an accordingly the method to the solution. thank you very much for helping

Comment: I think your ratios should be recomputed, for the first  one, you have $$\frac{x.(n+1)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}$$ Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a good idea to use the "d'Alembert ratio test". For the first, one has
$$
\left|\frac{\frac{\left(n+1\right)!x^{\left(n+1\right)}}{\left(2\left(n+1\right)\right)!}}{\frac{n!x^n}{\left(2n\right)!}}\right|=\frac{|x|.(n+1)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}
$$
which tends to $0$ for all $x$, so the radius is infinite.

For the second one, you cannot rearrange as you do and the ratio is
$$
\Big|\frac{(1-x)^5.5.(n+1)ln(n+1)}{(n)ln(n)}\Big|
$$
which tends to $5|(1-x)|^5$, can you then deduce the radius ? (it is a series "around $1$" however).

Comment: if i am not mistaken, i need that the limit will be less than 1, which means that i have to solve the inequality: $5|(1-x)|^5<1$, which gives me that the radius is: $\frac{5^{\frac{4}{5}}}{5}$. is that correct?

Comment: Yes for the principle and the radius then $$\frac{5^{\frac{4}{5}}}{5}=5^{-\frac{1}{5}}$$

Comment: thank you very much for helping me and guiding me. it really helped me to understand this subject better

Comment: This is my pleasure. I was guided myself ... Never hesitate to ask and submit

Answer (score 1):

In your first series you mentioned " since x=0, does it mean that it converges for all x?  in (−∞,∞)" You should rephrase your sentence as " $$\left|\frac{x}{2}\right|\cdot \lim \:_{n\to \infty \:}\left(\left|\frac{1}{2n+1}\right|\right)=0 $$ for every x, the series converges for $ x\in (-\infty, \infty )$

For your second series you have splitted one series into product of two series which is not allowed. However, you have started with the right step of the Root Test.

Comment: thank you for correcting me and explaining the correct way to write the solution

Comment: Welcome and thanks for attention.